# Bluetooth write function does not work

Tags: java, android

I have a Stringbuffer that keeps asci to hex value. (Not empty) and than i want to send with bluetooth. But i have a null object erorr but does not null.
(I am working on the fragment that is include bluetoothservice.java)

```
 BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
...
    for (char c: ch) {
        int i= (int) c;
        sbuffer.append(Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
        text.setText(sbuffer);
    }
```

....

If i press the send button, my hex sstringbuffer has to send bluetooth but doesnt work correctly.

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(sbuffer!=null) {
            byte[] bytes = sbuffer.toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
            mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
        }
    }
});
```

Bluetoothconnection.java

```
package com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;


public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try{
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            }

            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
                ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /**
     Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     **/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try{
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");

                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage", incomingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }







        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }

}
```

This is my log.cat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.BluetoothConnectionService.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.OTA_Update$1.onClick(OTA_Update.java:82)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21215)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
```

**EDIT 1 on the send message fragment** but does not work again. I cant connect with the bluetoothservice.java

```
public class OTA_Update extends Fragment {
    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private View convertView;
    String data;
    StringBuffer  sbuffer= new StringBuffer();
    TextView text;
    int read;
    int data_set;
    Button send;
    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ota__update, container, false);

            text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            InputStream  is =this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blink);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is));
            send =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.send);
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            if(is!=null){

                try {
                    while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        char [] ch =data.toCharArray();

                        for (char c: ch) {
                            int i= (int) c;
                            sbuffer.append(Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
                            text.setText(sbuffer);

                        }

                    }

                    is.close();

                }
                 catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(sbuffer!=null) {

                        byte[] bytes = sbuffer.toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);

                    }
                }
            });
        }




        return convertView;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate mBluetoothConnection, as it is null it raise the NullPointerException. Give more code to see where you declare/initialize (or not) the variable mBluetoothConnection.

Comment: @CKocar The error is raised on another file, when you press the button, because you never instancied the mBluetoothConnection, not inside the class, where do you declare AND initialize the variable mBluetoothConnection ?

Comment: it is 3. fragment i connected first fragment and than 2th fragmen getting value from the other devices correctly but 3th fragment cant send message

Comment: and top of the code i added     BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;

Comment: Check how you pass the argument then. Before calling the myBlue.write() you will see that it's not initialized, analyze where you put it or pass the code :/.

Comment: i see data on textview before calling mbluetoothconnection.write

Comment: i added                         mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
code before the press button but doesnt work again.

Comment: I added to   if(mConnectedThread !=null ){
            // Create temporary object


            // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
            //perform the write
            mConnectedThread.write(out);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "mConnectedThread empty ");


        }  on the write() function bluetoothconnectionservice.java and i am seeing now mConnectedThread empty  so how can i initilaze ?